# FileNotFoundException when trying to read a file I've written

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write an object (pilotRecord) to a file and read it back again. I understood that I didn't need to specify a path as it is internal to my app, so I want all files deleted if the app is uninstalled.

Here's my code:

```
    fileoutputstream = openFileOutput("test1", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "loadPilotRecord: "+fileoutputstream.toString());
    objectoutputstream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileoutputstream);
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "loadPilotRecord: "+objectoutputstream.toString());
    objectoutputstream.writeObject(pilotRecord);
    objectoutputstream.close();
    fileoutputstream.close();

    fileinputstream = new FileInputStream("test1");
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "loadPilotRecord: "+fileinputstream.toString());
    objectinputstream = new ObjectInputStream(fileinputstream);
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "loadPilotRecord: "+objectinputstream.toString());
    pilotRecord = (PilotRecord)objectinputstream.readObject();
    objectinputstream.close();
    fileinputstream.close();
```

My problem is that I get a FileNotFoundException on the following line in the above code:
fileinputstream = new FileInputStream("test1");
I'm not really sure how to find out what path it is using, or maybe there is a more obvious problem I'm just not seeing.
Sorry if this is a bit basic, but I'm still trying to find my feet.
The Log.d statements just output the class name and an Id.

TIA,

- Frink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried openfileinput("test1) instead of new FileInputStream("test1")?

Comment: Cheers. That worked a treat, thanks. Not sure why
new FileInputStream("test1")
didn't work tho as it was copied from an example

Answer (score 1):

To find out which path is actually used try:

```
File f = new File("test1");
Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Look at this location if the file is really created - if not, you won't be able to read.

EDIT: removed the guess with flush which was quite some nonsense

Comment: -1 - You *do not* need to flush a stream before closing it.  The close will do a flush.  Anyway, that would not cause a `FileNotFoundException`, because the file would be created by the FileOutputStream constructor invocation.

Comment: That returned /test1 so I suppose it is relative to the app, which makes sense. Don't think I can access that file area from within the emulator, which is a shame